# If else issue in stored procedure. I try to run this but get error at every "then" and at the "end"

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, if-statement

my else if is not working i think.

```
`elseif (oprtr = 1 and datetype = 0)
then
INSERT INTO PURGE_CONTACT SELECT SEQID,SITEID,DETAILID,DETAILSITE from CONTACT WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CREATED) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created)
                                                                                AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CREATED) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created)
                                                                                AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM CREATED) = EXTRACT(DAY FROM created);

elseif (oprtr = 2 and datetype = 0)
then
INSERT INTO PURGE_CONTACT SELECT SEQID,SITEID,DETAILID,DETAILSITE from CONTACT WHERE CREATED > created;

elseif (oprtr = 0 and datetype = 1)
then
INSERT INTO PURGE_CONTACT SELECT SEQID,SITEID,DETAILID,DETAILSITE from CONTACT WHERE LASTMODIFIED < created;

elseif (oprtr = 1 and datetype = 1)
then
INSERT INTO PURGE_CONTACT SELECT SEQID,SITEID,DETAILID,DETAILSITE from CONTACT WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM LASTMODIFIED) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created)
                                                                                AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM LASTMODIFIED) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created)
                                                                                AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM LASTMODIFIED) = EXTRACT(DAY FROM created);

elseif (oprtr = 2 and datetype = 1)
then
INSERT INTO PURGE_CONTACT SELECT SEQID,SITEID,DETAILID,DETAILSITE from CONTACT WHERE LASTMODIFIED > created;
end if;
```

`

Comment: No, the `ELSEIF` needs to be spelt `ELSIF`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by the misspelling of `ELSIF` as `ELSEIF`.

As a matter of interest, this might be a good place to use CASE:

```
case datetype
  when 0 then
    case oprtr
      when 0 then
        INSERT INTO PURGE_CONTACT SELECT SEQID,SITEID,DETAILID,DETAILSITE from CONTACT WHERE CREATED < created;
      when 1 then
        INSERT INTO PURGE_CONTACT SELECT SEQID,SITEID,DETAILID,DETAILSITE from CONTACT WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CREATED) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created)
                                                                                AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CREATED) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created)
                                                                                AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM CREATED) = EXTRACT(DAY FROM created);
      when 2 then
        INSERT INTO PURGE_CONTACT SELECT SEQID,SITEID,DETAILID,DETAILSITE from CONTACT WHERE CREATED > created;
      end case;
  when 1 then
    case oprtr
      when 0 then
        INSERT INTO PURGE_CONTACT SELECT SEQID,SITEID,DETAILID,DETAILSITE from CONTACT WHERE LASTMODIFIED < created;
      when 1 then
        INSERT INTO PURGE_CONTACT SELECT SEQID,SITEID,DETAILID,DETAILSITE from CONTACT WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM LASTMODIFIED) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created)
                                                                                AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM LASTMODIFIED) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created)
                                                                                AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM LASTMODIFIED) = EXTRACT(DAY FROM created);
      when 2 then
        INSERT INTO PURGE_CONTACT SELECT SEQID,SITEID,DETAILID,DETAILSITE from CONTACT WHERE LASTMODIFIED > created;
    end case;
end case;
```

However, you would need to add `else null;` to each `case` if other values of datetype and oprtr may be encountered.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I cant believe i made that spelling mistake :\

Answer (score 2):

Try `ELSIF` instead of `ELSEIF`